# read string and compare with certain value

Tags: c

I want to read a string from a console application and compare it:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

char* answer;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   printf("(yes/no):");
   scanf("%s", &answer);
   if (answer=="yes")
   {
      printf("Yes");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Exiting...");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I always get the message `Exiting...` when I put `yes`. How is it possible that I read the correct value of `yes` but it is not detected by the comparison - `answer=="yes"` -?

Also tried this:

```
    #include "string.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdafx.h"

    char answer[100];

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
       printf("(yes/no):");
       scanf("%s", answer);
       if (!strcmp(answer,"yes"))
       {
          printf("Yes");
       }
       else
       {
          printf("Exiting...");
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

this led me to the 2nd option of `"Exiting..."` as well. What is the error here?

Comment: Have you even tried searching "string compare c"?

Comment: Here char* answer is a pointer to hold an address of single character variable but not a string

Comment: `char* answer;` here answer is a Pointer, where exactly does point `*answer` ? you need answer[SIZE] or `malloc` for this here. There is no need of `&` in front of `&answer` because `answer` is a pointer. Probably the best choice is `char answer[SIZE]` ==>> `scanf("%SIZE-1s", answer);`

Answer (score 5):

Many problems in your code

1) You did not allocate memory for `answer`. Do

```
answer = malloc(100);
```

*Do not forget to `free(answer)` it later though.*

OR

You can also use arrays directly since you do not need dynamic memory

```
char answer[100];
```

---

2) You need to `char *` to `printf()` not `char **`. Do

```
scanf("%s", answer);
```

---

3) Use `strcmp` to compare strings, not `==`.

```
if (!strcmp(answer, "yes")
{
    printf("Yes");
}
```

`!` is there because, `strcmp` returns `0` when the `string`s match.

---

4) You should also check for return values, like here for `scanf()`.

```
if (scanf("%s", answer) != 1)
{
    printf("scanf failed");
    exit(0);
}
```

---

5) You should also mention the number of `char`s to be read by `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.

```
scanf("%99s", answer)
```

For a `char array[100]` of size `100`, one should give `99` to keep place for the null character `\0`.

Comment: do you need _malloc_ here?

Comment: Always prevent buffer overflow and check return values.  Should be `if (1 == scanf("%100s", answer))`

Comment: @stark, thanx, added.

Comment: @stark: good advice, but `scanf` is full of surprises: you should write `scanf("%99s", answer)` for a `char array[100]`.  Avoid confusing the OP with the `malloc` alternative.

Comment: @chqrlie, i gave the `malloc()` example because he started with a `pointer to char` and not an array.

Comment: Yes, like @chqrlie said, it should be `"%99s"` and not `"%s"`.

Comment: @Michi, added.. Thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: @chqrlie, Thanx for the suggestion

Comment: @Haris and you got my UP Vote,  I think that, there is no need of malloc for small things like this. There is a `free` needed also. Any way good answer.

Comment: @Michi, that was crucial, thanx for this suggestion also, added.

Comment: @Haris I used strcmp with string.h but I get this error: error C3861: 'strcmp': identifier not found

Comment: @tselios, I think you  are running the program in some other environment.

Comment: @Haris there was a problem with the order of header definition this is the correct order #include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string.h>

Comment: @Haris I used strcmp like you suggest, the answer var is read properly but the comparison leads to the 2nd option of "Exiting..." again, what is the problem here? I also defined answer as char answer[100]

Comment: @tselios, Can you edit the question and add the new code. Do not remove the old code, just add the new one at the bottom with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings, you should use `strcmp()`.

That said, `answer` is not allocated memory. You need to either use an array or use dynamic memory allocation to get the proper memory allocated to this before you can actually use `answer`.

Basically, you scan statement should look like

```
scanf("%s", answer);
```

with proper memory allocated to `answer` beforehand.

Comment: `strncmp(char *string1, char *string2, int n)` is the version that should be used, to prevent any funny business you might not catch otherwise.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s", answer);` prevents buffer overflow as poorly as `gets()`.  Recommend adding a width limit or using `fgets()`.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner: I fail to see the need for `strncmp` where `strcmp` is appropriate. Both `"yes"` and `answer` will be property null terminated, provided `answer` is correctly defined and `scanf` is invoked properly.  If not, `strncmp` cannot help, you will get undefined behavior.